# Django 1.5 CSRF Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to create a web app that makes Ajax calls when certain buttons are clicked, updating data in my models and displaying the updated data. Here is my template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/workout1.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

    <span id="squats">Squats:  {{ user.weekOne.squats }} done.<br/></span>
    <span id="lunges">Lunges: {{ user.weekOne.lunges }} done.<br /></span>
    <span id="stairDays">Stair Days: {{ user.weekOne.stairDaysCount }}<br/></span>
    <span id="skipStairs">Skip Stairs: {{ user.weekOne.skipStairs }}<br /></span>
        <form>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="squats" id="squatsVal" value="Squats" />
            <input type="submit" id="submitSquats" value="Add Squats"/><br />
        </form>

        <form>
            <input type="text" name="lunges" value="Lunges" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Lunges" /><br />
        </form>

        <form>
            <input type="submit" value="Stairs skipped."><br />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I use Django's [suggested code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) for dealing with Ajax and CSRF. Here is my resultant jQuery:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
// Boilerplate for handling CSRF, from Django's website

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
};

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
// the actual Ajax
$("#submitSquats").click(function() {
    var exercise = "squats";
    var amount = $('#squats').val();
    var data = {'exercise': exercise, 'amount': amount};
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"submitWorkout1",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            $('#squats').html('<span>Success</span>');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Finally, here is the view that handles the incoming Ajax request and returns a response for the Ajax to work with:

```
def submitWorkout1(request):
    exercise = request.POST['exercise']
    amount = request.POST['amount']
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    exercise, amount = user.WeekOne.updateExercise(exercise, amount)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'result': 'success', exercise: amount}))
```

Unfortunately, when I try to click on the Submit Squats button and run the jQuery, I get a `CSRF Token Missing or Incorrect` error message. Moreover, if I use a @csrf_exempt identifier on top of my view for testing purposes, I get this error:

```
"Key 'exercise' not found in <QueryDict: {u'undefined': [u'', u'']}>"
```

So even if I were to fix the CSRF problem, it appears there is something else wrong with my Ajax code. But I want to fix both problems. Help!

Updated code (see catherine's post below):

HTML:

```
<body>

    <span id="squats">Squats:  {{ user.weekOne.squats }} done.<br/></span>
    <span id="lunges">Lunges: {{ user.weekOne.lunges }} done.<br /></span>
    <span id="stairDays">Stair Days: {{ user.weekOne.stairDaysCount }}<br/></span>
    <span id="skipStairs">Skip Stairs: {{ user.weekOne.skipStairs }}<br /></span>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url workout_game_app.views.submitWorkout1 %}"> 
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="squats" id="squatsVal" value="Squats" />
            <input type="submit" id="submitSquats" value="Add Squats"/><br />
        </form>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitSquats").click(function() {
        var exercise = "squats";
        var amount = $('#squats').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/workout_game_app/workouts/submitWorkout1/",
            data: {'exercise': exercise,
                    'amount:': amount,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function() {
                $('#squats').html('<span>Success</span>');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

view:

```
def submitWorkout1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':


        exercise = request.POST['exercise']
        amount = request.POST['amount']
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        exercise, amount = user.WeekOne.updateExercise(exercise, amount)
        data = simplejson.dumps({
            'result': 'success',
            'exercise': exercise,
            'amount': amount
            }, indent=4)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

URL:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'workout_game_app.views.index'),
        url(r'^signup$/', 'workout_game_app.views.signup'),
        url(r'^login$/', 'workout_game_app.views.login_view'),
        url(r'^logout/$', 'workout_game_app.views.logout_view'),
        url(r'^workouts/workout1/$', 'workout_game_app.views.workout1'),
        url(r'^workouts/submitWorkout1/$',
            'workout_game_app.views.submitWorkout1'),
```

Comment: As the exception tells you, you might need to put single quotes around your url argument inside url tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url tells you more about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i were you, i would remove that AJAX below the "// Boilerplate for handling CSRF, from Django's website" comment and replace "the actual ajax" with this:

```
// the actual Ajax
$("#submitSquats").click(function() {
    var form = $(this).parent();
    $.post(
        "submitWorkout1", //url
        form.serialize(), //data
        function() {      //success method
            $('#squats').html('<span>Success</span>');
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

If you are getting a 403 error, it must be because you are not sending the csrf token... This is easily done with `form.serialize()`, together with all form data....

Comment: +1. I remember pulling my hair out trying to solve the 403 error. I use serialize and magic, everything works :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove your script for csrf_token implementation. Just simply add csrf_token in your ajax function.

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitSquats").click(function() {
        var exercise = "squats";
        var amount = $('#squatsVal').val();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/workout_game_app/workouts/submitWorkout1/",
            data: { 
                'exercise': exercise, 
                'amount': amount,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
            },
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#squats').html('<span>Success</span>');
                alert(data); //for testing
            },
            error: function(ts) { 
                alert(ts.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And in your views.py

```
def submitWorkout1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        exercise = request.POST['exercise']
        amount = request.POST['amount']
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        exercise, amount = user.WeekOne.updateExercise(exercise, amount) 
        data = simplejson.dumps({
             'result': 'success', 
             'exercise': exercise,
             'amount': amount 
           }, indent=4)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

**urls.py**

dont forget to put `/` before `$`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'workout_game_app.views.index'),
    url(r'^signup/$', 'workout_game_app.views.signup'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'workout_game_app.views.login_view'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'workout_game_app.views.logout_view'),
    url(r'^workouts/workout1/$', 'workout_game_app.views.workout1'),
    url(r'^workouts/submitWorkout1/$',
        'workout_game_app.views.submitWorkout1'),
```

**template**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url workout_game_app.views.submitWorkout1 %}"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="squats" id="squatsVal" value="Squats" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitSquats" value="Add Squats"/><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Okay, added urls.py to the end of the code. Added method="POST" to the form. Changed the url to /submitWorkout1 in the Ajax. still getting the 403 though.

Comment: Just added that, too, but the result is still the same. :-( I'll update my code to reflect the new additions.

Comment: I've double checked all of my code and it seems to match up, but I'm still getting that pesky 403 error. I really appreciate your help though catherine.

Comment: I added the action= thing to my form code as well and that creates a new error: `NoReverseMatch at /workouts/workout1/`

Comment: update your codes in the question. It's must not be `workout1`, it must `submitWorkout1`. Please trace your codes and compare it. I'm really sure you missed something.

Comment: added the traceback. my post is getting pretty crazy

Comment: your error is pointing to other url. Where did you use this url `/workouts/workout1/`?

Comment: That's the URL of the page with the form on it.

Comment: your urls.py has an error, you've mistaken to put `/` after `$`. Have you seen it?

Comment: Oops, that was actually an error in copying the code over. The actual code doesn't have that.

Comment: Yes. On the user's main page they can click on a list of workouts, the link for Workout One is `<a href="/workouts/workout1">Workout One</a>`.

Comment: No, sorry just change that into `<a href="{% url workout_game_app.views.workout1 %}">Workout One</a>`

Comment: Now I get `NoReverseMatch at / - 'url' requires a non-empty first argument` for that link.

Comment: Turns out if I put the url argument in quotes, like 'workout_game_app.views.workout', it works. Buuuuuuut, I still get the 403.

Comment: There's no traceback at this point, Django just generates a 403 that says `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

Comment: Of course. I'll try a few other methods and see if anything works... I'll update the post if so. I really, REALLY appreciate your help and patience catherine, you're awesome!

Comment: I have this included: 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'

Comment: did you try to change ajax call with jquery post, as i answered? Try doing that to see if you continue getting that 403 error...

Comment: Yes, turns out the serializing the form was the magic I needed. Still curious why the method outlined by catherine isn't working though.

Comment: i think the problem was that you were using `{{csrf_token}}` in your javascript code and that code wasn't inside your html but included in `head` of html as another file. Django wasn't replacing that piece of string with the needed token and because of that you were having that ugly 403 error...